# File framework is not there

Tags: python, macos, pynput

I want to try the pynput module, but it failed to work not giving me an error. I try to find the pynput module and when I pip install my terminal says that it is in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages. However I did not have a Frameworks folder in my library folder. I have looked everywhere and it does not exist. Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: I feel you're not looking into the right ```library``` folder. Did you try: Right click on Finder -> ```Go to Folder``` and enter ```/Library```

Comment: Yes on the desktop page I just click go, and then Library. If it helps that is the one with the roman building logo with application support.

Comment: In your terminal - type ```where python```. It will probably return path with Frameworks. Then copy that path and type ```ls -l <path>```. If it tells you - no such folder/file - then you probably messed up with your system and python should not work at all.